# How to get extra information from the highest values from SQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a derived a table with 3 columns :

```
computerID 
ScanDate
vulnerability level.
```

I want to group by **computerID** and get the vulnerability level of the latest **scanDate** WITHOUT having to add an inner join (the table is pretty big).

Is it possible?

Comment: We need Table structure, sample data, expected output and your attempted query. If you can provide a SQLFiddle for all, it would be great.

Comment: in short. no it isn't.

Comment: just noticed its a derived table. what's it derived from? you'd probably have to go back to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want `Without join keyword`!!, you can do this :

```
select * 
from your_table t
where (computerID, ScanDate) in
      (
        select computerID, max(ScanDate)
        from your_table t1
        where t1.computerID=t.computerID
        )
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51bc1/2)

Comment: subqueries are rarely better than joins.

Comment: IT DEPENDS ON JOIN CONDITIONS AND CAPACITY OF DATA.

Comment: what? it depends on the query optimizer, which is almost always better and optimizing joins than it is subqueries. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/rewriting-subqueries.html

Comment: isn't this getting decomposed just as an inner join in the background?

Comment: this was another solution, you can test it by comparing it with the inner join version which has group by, however yes in fact this acts almost similar to inner join

Comment: uh.. yours has an implicit group by?

Comment: anyway. end of the day. just ran both queries through explain, using a horribly contrived view as the source, and the plans are almost identical. subquery performance has improved since the last i looked at it (granted, quite a few versions ago)

Comment: yes a join may be wrote in subquery form and a subquery also may be wrote in join form, however we can't say which is always better.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, using `not exists` can work better than `group by`.  Not always, but it is worth a try:

```
select d.*
from derived d
where not exists (select 1
                  from derived d2
                  where d2.computer = d.computer and d2.scandate > d.scandate
                 );
```

Alternatively, if you are already doing a `group by`, then there is the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select computer, max(scandate),
       substring_index(group_concat(vulnerability order by scandate desc), ',', 1)
from derived d2
group by computer;
```

You need to be a little careful with this.  If `vulnerability` is a string and can contain commas, then a different separator needs to be used.  If `vulnerability` is not a string, it will be converted to one.  And, if there are too many dates, then you might hit the limits of the `group_concat()` (the maximum length of the `group_concat()` result is controlled by a parameter, so this can also be fixed).

Comment: i like the trick.  although execution plans look frighteningly similar for every answer here so far

Answer (score 0):

I know of no way to accomplish what you want without joining, or subqueries.

Here's a join that'll do it - although it might be better performing to build it off the tables that form your derived table:

```
select t1.computerid, t1.vulnerability_level, t1.scandate
  from threats t1
    left join threats t2
      on t1.computerid = t2.computerid and t1.scandate < t2.scandate
    where t2.scandate is null;
```

assuming your derived table is called threats.